# How to make a custom route with any-string-part/number-part pointing to an existing page?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, routing

I've got a page with my own widget inside of it which needs some params from the url to produce dynamic db results - don't worry everything is sanitized well and I only let this part out to keep this slim and concentrated on routes which is the crucial part for me ( being wp newbie).

Is it possible to set a custom route in WP with a string and number inside of it and let it point to an existing page identified by slug?
I found somewhere route examples but not with a wildcard string and only working with templates - in this case I need an page as the endpoint.

In **laravel 3** I would do the following:

```
// Calling following url:
// http://mypage.com/items/my-red-toy/123
//
// Will produce:
// You String is: my-red-toy
// The Number is: 123

Route::get('pageslug/(:any)/(:num)', function($anystring, $number)
{
    echo "You String is: ".$anystring;
    echo "The Number is: ".$number;
});
```

Or as rewrite rule in .htaccess (even if not a pretty solution...) :

```
RewriteRule ^items/([a-z]*)?/?([0-9]*)?/?$ /items [L]
```

This rewrite rule would work in my usual php pages but only works partialy in wp. 
It'll work with:

```
http://mypage.com/items/12314
```

but not with

```
http://mypage.com/items/my-red-toy
```

nor with

```
http://mypage.com/items/my-red-toy/1231
```

Somehow only one uri segment with numbers inside seems to be allowed.

Could someone point me to the solution? I'm to new to Wordpress so I don't know where to start...

Comment: If you feel home with Laravel routing I suggest [this](http://rules.zoomlab.it/) plugin (it's mine). Be aware it's beta version.

Comment: Looks promising so far. Why don't you post it as a regular answer? And if you would be so kindly please add an brief example. I'm sure that there're some more interested people around.

Comment: I don't think the mine is really an answer, and also this is not the place for my plugin usage example. However I write [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/bN96UYkJ) for you.

Comment: Wow you made my day Giuseppe! This works like a charm and indeed THIS IS THE SOLUTION for my problem even if you don't post it as answer which is very pity. I think that all the folks should know about your great plugin! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: if you want to understand how this actually works in WordPress, have a look at [`add_rewrite_rule`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) in codex.